# How could I find what php is running when it slows down, like a sleep() command?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, nginx, debugging

Is there any built in debugging options or some way to monitor what php is doing? I have a few scripts that take long to load. Like is there a way to find a random sleep() input buried in the code? One script I had, I found a loose sleep command, but I found that accidentally, was wondering if I could've found it without explicitly looking for it.

Thanks

Comment: PHP itself offers "ticks" (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.register-tick-function.php), apart from that your typical approach would be a profiler or a debugger, both of which you typically can only use when you operate the http server or the fastcgi container yourself.

Comment: Oh, and if you really assume there is a "sleep()" burried somewhere (why should that be the case?), then you obviously also can simply "grep" for that through the files ...

Answer (score 1):

You want to make use of [slow PHP-FPM logging](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/how-to-log-and-fix-slow-php-requests).

E.g. this PHP-FPM pool configuration will log PHP traceback for scripts running 3 or more seconds:

```
slowlog = /srv/www/example.com/logs/slow.log
request_slowlog_timeout = 3s
```